# Count occurance of multiple columns by group in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I have a df that looks like this:

```
Room  Item  Red Square  
Basement  Ball  TRUE  FALSE
Basement  Basket  TRUE  TRUE
Basement  Table FALSE TRUE
Basement  Desk TRUE TRUE
```

I want to count the number of Square, Red, and both square + red items, so the final DF looks like this:

```
Room Square Red Both
Basement 1 1 2
```

I tried

```
df %>% 
group_by(Room, Square, Red) %>%
count()
```

to give me count of the categories, but I'm not sure how to format it as I want it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this pipeline it is necessary to name the newly-created variables with different names so that, when you use `summarise`, the second and third variables don't use the newly-created variable `Square`. I later rename them within the same pipeline.

```
df %>% 
  group_by(Room) %>% 
  summarise(
    Square_new = sum(Square & !Red),
    Red_new = sum(Red & !Square),
    Both_new = sum(Square & Red)
  ) %>% 
  rename(Square = Square_new, Red = Red_new, Both = Both_new)
```

Output

```
# A tibble: 1 x 4
#   Room     Square   Red  Both
#   <chr>     <int> <int> <int>
# 1 Basement      1     1     2
```

Comment: Renaming should be done using the `rename()` function from dplyr so the last line in the pipeline becomes: `%>% rename(Square = Square_new, Red = Red_new, Both = Both_new)`.

Comment: @pieterbons good suggestion, I took the first option that came to mind. You can edit my answer if you'd like :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this. First add `Both` category. Second. Set `Red` and `Square` to `FALSE` if `Both == TRUE`. Then sum.

```r
df <- read.table(text = "Room  Item  Red Square  
Basement  Ball  TRUE  FALSE
Basement  Basket  TRUE  TRUE
Basement  Table FALSE TRUE
Basement  Desk TRUE TRUE", header = TRUE)

library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(Both = Red & Square) %>%
  mutate_at(c("Red", "Square"), ~ .x & !Both) %>%
  group_by(Room) %>% 
  summarise_at(c("Red", "Square", "Both"), sum)
#> # A tibble: 1 x 4
#>   Room       Red Square  Both
#>   <fct>    <int>  <int> <int>
#> 1 Basement     1      1     2
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out, not as elegant as @Ric S answer but:

```
df2 <- df %>%
  group_by(Room) %>%
  summarise(Square = sum(df$Square == "TRUE" & df$Red == "FALSE"), Red = sum(df$Red == "TRUE" & df$Square == "FALSE"), both = sum(df$Square == "TRUE" & df$Red == "TRUE"))
```